# Import C repository to iOS Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have a core C project with my logic and want to use for both platform (iOS and Android). In android I pointed to my remote repository and download it via Gradle, everything working fine.

I'm new to iOS dev so I want to know if I can have a Xcode project, maybe using CocoaPod, that imports my C Project and configure itself to be used by my `.swift` files.

Maybe make my C project a importable Pod, is it Possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Xcode natively supports C-code. When adding your C-files to your project, Xcode will ask if you want to create a bridging header file. In there, you just paste `#import "NAME"` and you can directly access that code in all Swift files. Xcode even allows you to create C and C++ files when clicking "add new file".

Comment: This part I know, what I'd like to have is some code that automatically downloads my C repo. Like `pod install` or something like it! Thanks !

Comment: You can do anything you want at that point, that's no problem at all. :) Maybe a private Pod helps you out here: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: I've read that also, my doubt actually is how do I turn my C project into a Pod, it's kinda obscure to me...

Comment: There's a complete guide about turning your project into a pod on the website of cocoapods.https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html